# list items in ordered list are breaking to a new line after digit

Tags: html, windows, internet-explorer

The client we have for this site is using an old version of both internet explorer and windows. The ol is simple.

```
<ol>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
</ol>
```

In internet explorer this being shows like this.

```
1. 
Item 1
2.  
Item 2
```

Instead of

```
1. Item 1
2. Item 2
```

Is there an easy way to go about fixing this?

Comment: what happens when you give the list items the style of display:block ?

Comment: When I did that, it made the number before the item disappear altogether

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
li {
  display: inline;
}
```

See number 9 in this post, maybe your problem is described there, too:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/9-most-common-ie-bugs-and-how-to-fix-them--net-7764

Comment: This helped me figure out the issue. The actual items were wrapped in a span tag. `li span{ display: inline; }` worked